# Error while installing CPLEX 12.6 for Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cplex

I am trying to install CPLEX for python from the setup.py file existing in ILOG directory. 
I am working on windows 8 32bit and python 2.7. I am using this command for installing:

```
python setup.py install
```

But I get this error,

```
error: could not create 'build': access is denied.
```

Is it due to the permission? How can I fix this?
thanks

Comment: Having this same issue almost 6 years later.

Comment: Answer is correct.

Comment: what do you do if you dont have administrator permissions

Answer (score 7):

I have no idea about CPLEX but processes in windows8 usually don't get write access to certain directories.

You could try to make your call "python setup.py install" in a cmd started as adminstrator, for example: windows key, search "cmd", right click, "run as adminstrator" ...

Comment: I can confirm that this is the correct solution.  When opening the command prompt or anaconda prompt on windows, right-click on 'Run as Administrator'.